# net.tcp wcf service (windows service hosted) in domain server and client outside of domain

Tags: wcf, net.tcp

I have a wcf service (with net.tcp binding) hosted at windows service and a wpf client. when I run the service in a server outside the company's domain it works excellent, the problem is when I host the service in a server inside the company's domain, and try to run the wpf app in a client outside of the company domain.
I'm getting the same error, "The Socket connection was aborted..."
I try with Security Mode None, Transport and the same result.
My question is, what is the correct way to do that? I mean host the wcf net TCP service in a domain server and call it from a client outside of domain?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure your corporate firewall allows arbitrary clients to call into your network directly?

Comment: Yes, the other network is a process network. The server have access to the corporate network and the process network as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change the binding from net.tcp to wshttp and the service works fine!
Server with the corporate domain and client without corporate domain
The thing is I need the make this work with net.tcp

Comment: Different application scenarios have different security strategy, authentication, authorization. We use Nettcpbinding in an intranet application scenario. Considering the unsafety of the internet. We use the Wshttpbinding with encryption and authentication mode.
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/431291/wcf-services-choosing-the-appropriate-wcf-binding

Answer (score 0):

Neither a Windows Domain nor DNS have anything to do with WCF/TCP if you don't explicitly make it so.

Assuming the address you gave actually leads to the PC you host your service on (so no local IP addresses) and nothing in between (like a firewall) blocks the connection, it should work.

The correct way is to make sure client and server can talk to each other. If it's different networks, you will need [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) and if one is a corporate network I'd be very surprised to see no [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) that you need to configure.

As a first step, try to [ping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)) your target machine from your client machine.

Comment: The communication between machines works fine, the server has 2 networks, the corporative with the firewall of the company and the local process network. the local process network its an internal network without a firewall

Comment: I guess you will need to post a network setup and your exact configuration.